# How can i convert stereo pcm samples to mono samples using naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

How can i convert stereo pcm samples to mono samples using naudio?

or converting an stereo mp3 file to mono raw samples!

i try this befor :

```
for (int u = 0; u < output.Length; u+=4)
            {
                byte[] Lbuffer = new byte[2];
                byte[] Rbuffer = new byte[2];
                Lbuffer[0] = output[u + 0];
                Lbuffer[1] = output[u + 1];
                Rbuffer[0] = output[u + 2];
                Rbuffer[1] = output[u + 3];

                Int16 leftSample = BitConverter.ToInt16(Lbuffer, 0);
                Int16 rightSample = BitConverter.ToInt16(Rbuffer, 0);

                Int16 mixedMono = (Int16)(0.5f * (float)leftSample + (float)rightSample);
                Byte[] mixedMonoBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(mixedMono);

                mono[counter] = mixedMonoBytes[0];
                mono[counter+1] = mixedMonoBytes[1];


                //mono[counter] = Convert.ToByte((Convert.ToInt16(buffer[0]) + Convert.ToInt16(buffer[2]))/2);
                //mono[counter+1] = Convert.ToByte((Convert.ToInt16(buffer[0]) + Convert.ToInt16(buffer[2]))/2);
                counter += 2;
            }
```

but it does not work currently! it result has noises! 
output is an array that contains raw samples!

Comment: to convert stereo to mono, you generally take the two samples of one stereo frame and calculate the avergage of them. the result is your mono sample.

Comment: please read my edit !

Comment: @user2326338 perhaps you could give more detail as to what exactly isn't working?  You are hearing noise in your output file?

Comment: The way you mixed left and right is 0.5 * left + right, which is wrong; should be 0.5 * (left + right).  Also, noise could be caused by overflow; use saturation arithmetic like I suggested in my answer.  Another thing to check is the byte order of the data -- does it match the endianness of the machine, or do you need to byte-swap it?

Comment: Richard Walters! you r right! 0.5 * (left + right) is correct !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @daniel-s pointed out, to convert PCM samples from stereo (2 channels) to mono (1 channel), you can simply take the average of the two channels: for every sample, take the value from the left channel, add the value from the right channel, and divide by 2.  Use [saturation arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic) to avoid overflows.

To convert an MP3 file to raw (PCM) samples, you need to run the MP3 file through a file parser and MP3 bitstream decoder.  There are many libraries and applications out there to do this; for example, see [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

[Edit] I forgot to mention, more importantly, NAudio supports decoding MP3 files through either ACM or DMO codec; see [NAudio - MP3](http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3) for examples.

Comment: You can use a multiplication instead : 0.5 * (1.0 + 1.0) = 1.0

Comment: Sure, if you don't mind using floating point types.  Sometimes that can be an issue, for example in some embedded environments.  Probably the best way to divide by two, if you don't mind truncating the fraction, is to do a bit-shift:  `(1 + 1) >> 1 = 1`

Comment: Totally agree with you :-)

Comment: some code example and I would press that up button